# Oracle Service Bus - Unix authorization over telnet

Tags: oracle, soa, telnet, osb, oracle-service-bus

I'm completely new to Oracle's Service Bus.
The problem I'm facing is that OSB 11g is to be used in a rather specific environment meaning - OSB needs to send CSV formatted messages over telnet to a Legacy System. Before that the connection must be authorized with a Unix login and password. As login/pass authorization is fairly simple with such transports as FTP or HTTP I came up with two solutions:

- developing a new socket transport with an appropriate authorization procedure (ie. using http://sadun-util.sourceforge.net/) basing on sample-transport that comes with the OSB installation
- JMS using JCA socket adapter and Java Callout with an authorization method in request pipeline - *is the one valid?*

My question is what is the best way to resolve the problem? 
Is there any preferred way of dealing with such problems?

Thanks in advance for your answers. 
Regards,
P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright,
after some testing and browsing I came to two conclusions.
Development of a custom transport is worthwile whenever the service you're accessing is to be widely used.
On the other hand you can use Java Callout that does custom handshake (this case login/password/accesskey in unix over telnet using apache commons). What is more, you can use a Service Account to authorize the user. 
In my case solution is like:
Business Service for Client Webservice. Proxy accessing BS with a Java Callout that does handshake. Next stage sends message and demands the request.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely clear of your infrastructure and requirements, but will try and shoot an arrow in the dark.

**OSB should broker your communications**. Hence, The setup would be as follows.

First, OSB exposes a proxy service with SFTP capabilities. To do this:
      1. Create **Proxy Service** -> **Any XML type** -> select **`SFTP` as protocol**
      2. **Enter the destination** as sftp://hostname/folder
      3. Configure this SFTP transport by providing all the required credentials and configuration

Next, wire this proxy service into your infrastructure, mandating all applications that need to send out file over SFTP to use this for transporting the file.

Comment: Hi CMR, thanks for your anwser, anyhow I guess you kinda misunderstood the concept. By CSV formatted messages I don't mean CSV files. I need to send the message over telnet to get a response.